# PayPal. Some required information is missing or incorrect. Please correct the fields below and try again

Tags: node.js, angular, paypal

I have a form with data, which I send to 'https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com' API by HTTP post query. I send 'requestString' as string with different values, joined by '&'. If I have value with quotes like - ' or " or  `- (example - Les Clefs d`Or Fund - see on the picture) - then I got such an error.

[image]

```
  public async sendPayPalRequest(
    donationInfo: DonationInfoModel,
    // urlBase: string,
  ): Promise<string> {
    const templateString = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    const transactionDetails: IPayPalTransactionInfo = {
      ....
      currency: 'USD',
      comment1: StringHelper.replaceQuotationWithBacktick(donationInfo.fundName),
      ....
    };

    ....

    const requestParameters = [];
    for (const key in transactionDetails) {
      if (transactionDetails.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        requestParameters.push(
          `${key.toUpperCase()}[${transactionDetails[key].length}]=${transactionDetails[key]}`,
        );
      }
    }
    const response = await axios.post(process.env.PAYPAL_TRANSACTION_URL, requestString, {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
    });
    return response.data;
  }
...
```

If I replace quotes with "", or "^" - the payment is successful.
Does anybody overcome such an issue?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You likely need to either have Axios build the post body by passing it an object or show how you are doing it (i.e. you are likely not composing `requestString` correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *payflowpro.paypal.com endpoint recognizes `[#]` length tags so the parser knows to ignore special characters in values like `&` or `=`.

```c
COMPANYNAME[14]=Ruff & Johnson

COMMENT1[7]=Level=5
```

Quotes, however, are not supported.

See the documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/payflow/integration-guide/simple-transaction/#link-usespecialcharactersinvalues